# How get past a “The semaphore timeout period has expired.” while trying to dump the firmware of an Eclipse T2810C MP4 player?

Tags: windows, firmware

I'm trying to use [s1fwx](http://s1mp3.w1r3.de/tools.s1fwx.html) to dump the firmware from my actions based MP4 player. It’s an Eclipse T2810C. Runs on an ATJ2257D. OS is a MIPS version of s1mp3. (ADPU mode, some weird extra stuff hidden inside the standard USB drive thing.)

However, the program just throws the whole “semaphore timeout period” thing.

Is there something I can do? Changing versions of Windows does *not* help. The MP4 player also drops to USB 1.1, if that helps.

Better yet, is there some ADPU utility on Linux that allows NAND readback? I'd 100% dump this Windows stuff and try that instead.

Comment: What is an “…actions based MP4 player…”? Maybe if you could provide the exact make and model of the player that would help?

Comment: An Eclipse t2810c. Runs on an ATJ2257D. OS is a MIPS version of s1mp3.